# Extract a row from a 3d numpy matrix

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matrix

I am currently having problems with a simple problem being extracting a row from a 3d numpy matrix.

Given a matrix [3,3,3] => I want to extract a row such as the output becomes [1,3,3]..

But how do i do that **without reshaping**? I seem to keep extracting [3,3]

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.random.rand(3,3,3)
>>> print a[0].shape
(3, 3)
```

Comment: The output is correct. You need to reshape it. `row = a[0].reshape(1,3,3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With any array shape, indexing with a scalar reduces the dimensions by 1.

```
 x[0]       # 1 to 0 (scalar)
 x[0,:], x[:,0]     # 2 to 1
 x[0,:,:], x[:,0,:]   # 3 to 2
```

You can retain the dimensions in several ways, by slicing or indexing with a list:

```
 x[[0],:,:]
 x[0:1,:,:]
```

or add 1 back in:

```
 x[0, None,:,:]  
 x[0,:,:][None,:,:]
 x[0,:,:].reshape(1,n,m)
```

`reshape` is cheap, even if it looks 'ugly'.  Don't be afraid to use it.